# How to Stop a Recursive Function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, recursion

I'm stuck looking for the right way to stop a setTimeout call recursive function. I want to be able to restart an animation without having to wait for the animation to finish.

Any help would be awesome!!

```js
var viewArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var started = 0;

function animator() {
  if (!started) {
    console.log("Start... ");
    started = 1;
    var i = 0;
    count = 1;

    (function iterator() { // <-- how can I kill this iterator function when the user clicks stop
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = viewArray[i];
      if (++i < viewArray.length) {
        setTimeout(iterator, 1000);
        count++
        if (count >= viewArray.length) {
          started = 0;
        } //when animation complete (number reaches 10) allow start animation button to work again 
      }
    })();

  } else {
    console.log("Wait..."); // inactivate button
  }

  started = 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="output" style="margin: 40px; font-size:130px"></div>
<div style="margin: 40px;">
  <button id="on" onclick="animator();">Start Animation</button>
</div>
<div style="margin: 40px;">
  <button id="off">Stop Animation</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout)

Comment: Calling setTimeout to set a new timeout for the same function isn't technically a recursive function.

Comment: I have but don't think I'm implementing it correctly. I'm missing something :(

Comment: There is no call to clearTimeout in your code, so yeah, you're missing something. :) Have you stored the timer id returned by setTimeout, so you can pass it to clearTimeout?

Comment: Ok, I wondered about that... I wasn't sure. @GolezTrol

Comment: @GolezTrol it is technically a recursive function, since the function uses itself.

Comment: @GolezTrol - The technical term for when a function uses setTimeout to call itself is "recurse-ish".

Comment: I tried the state variable and that definitely did the trick, but there was a slight delay closing the last iteration. I ended up going with clearTimeout, and that killed it right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily solve this with state. Simply add a variable to your code called

```
  var isRunning = false;
```

which it to `true` when you start the animation, and `false` to stop the animation. Then inside your `iterator` function, check to see if `isRunning` is `false`. If `isRunning === false`, you don't call the next `setTimeout`, hence stopping the animation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use setInterval/clearInterval outside your interval function. You definitely want recurring intervals instead of single timeouts when you think about it.

So basically:

```
var something;

function start() {
  something = setInterval(interval, 1000);
}

function interval() {
  //animation code
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(something);
}
```